# How to prevent Apache Solr from returning "suites" when searching for "suits" and vice versa?

Tags: search, solr

We are a listings/business directory company that uses Apache Solr 4.7.2.  When we do a search for "suits" in "Melbourne", our top two results are hotels that contain the word "suites" and the rest of the results are tailors, clothing retailers, etc., as expected.  How do I prevent Solr from including hotels/suites in a search for "suits"?

Answer (score 3):

This is due to stemming. There are two ways to handle it:

- Disable stemming completely by removing the stemming filter from schema.xml
- use [KeywordMarkFilter](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Language+Analysis#LanguageAnalysis-KeywordMarkerFilterFactory) if you just want to exclude specific keywords from being stemmed. In this particular case you would create a protwords.txt file with two lines, "suits" and "suites" (and any other keyword you want to protect from stemming)